# I need help with the following exercise: find where $g:[0,5]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and differentiable.

Tags: integration

$g(x)=\int_{2}^{x}{f(t)dt}$, where

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^2,\qquad\quad\,\, 0\le x\le 1 \\ 2, \qquad\qquad 1 < x \le 4 \\ x-2, \qquad 4 < x \le 5 \end{cases}.$$

I thought to calculate the integral function, so I wrote:

if $x\in [2,4]$, $g(x)=\int_{2}^{x}{2 dt}$

if $x\in ]4,5]$, $g(x)=\int_{2}^{4}{2 dt}+\int_{4}^{x}{(t-2) dt}$.

Is this correct? Can someone add the missing cases?

What changes with $k:[0,5]\to\Bbb R, k(x)=\begin{cases} f(x),\qquad\quad\,\, x \not = {1,3} \\ 1000, \qquad\qquad x\in{1,3} \end{cases}$?

Isn't' it integrable for the same reason f is?

Comment: Use begin{cases} and end{cases} for piecewise functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to conclude on the continuity and differentiability, you don't need to perform any calculations. Since $f$ is piecewise continuous, it is integrable, and $g(x) = \int_2^x f(t) dt$ is automatically continuous and differentiable everywhere in its domain. If you really want to explicitly compute $g(x)$, considerer these cases

1. If $1 \leq x \leq 4$
   $$
   g(x)= \int_2^x f(t) dt = \int_2^x 2 dt = [2t]_2^x = 2(x-2)
   $$
2. If $0 \leq x < 1$
   $$
   \int_2^x f(t) dt = \int_2^1 f(t) dt + \int_1^x f(t) dt = 2+[t^3/3]_1^x = 2+\frac 13(x^3 -1)
   $$

and so on...

Comment: Thank you. I don't have to split the interval of the first integral since $2\in[1,4]$,  right?

Comment: I wrote that f is integrable since it is bounded and it is discontinuous at just one point. How can I justify that it is bounded?

Comment: @Veronica, yes, that's it.

Comment: @Veronica The boundness does not justify the integrability... You have bounded functions that are not (Riemann) integrable. But you can justify boundeness easily using Bolzano's theorem (you can make the subintervals compact and still get a bound).

Comment: Isn't it a sufficient condition for Riemann integrability? A bounded function with a finite number of discontinuities?

Comment: @Veronica In that case yes, I was just saying that the boundness by itself does not imply integrability.

Comment: Yes, of course. I asked that because I wrote which is the discontinuity and why but I didn't prove the fact that it is bounded, I only said that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't $\int_{2}^{1}{f(t)}=-2$? Moreover, I cannot say that g is continuous everywhere from f since f is not continuous at x=1. So I have to check this point, right?